# laravel 5.5 passport with angular 4

Tags: angular, laravel-5, angular4-httpclient

I need to do the Laravel Passport authentication for API
and also need Angular 4 HTTP client with the canActive route. Please refer me the reference site or GitHub projects.

Answer (score -3):

https://laravel-angular.io/ should work for you. There is plenty DOC on the website :) good luck

Comment: this link for a project using "JWT Authentication" not Laravel Passport.